# Passing UIImage with segue

Tags: ios, uiimage, segue

I am reading data from the JSON object and pass the image property to other viewcontroller. Before I do it, I wanted to test the following code with hardcoded UiImage and it works perfectly fine.

```
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

        GrillMenuSingleFoodViewController *gVC = [segue destinationViewController];

        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"isMoreDetail"]) {

            [gVC setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Ali_nazik.jpg"]];

        }
}
```

But the following code is not working. Even though I am getting imagedata, once I pass to other viewcontroller it shows nil.

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

        GrillMenuSingleFoodViewController *gVC = [segue destinationViewController];

        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"isMoreDetail"]) {

            NSString *imageURLString=[menuArray[indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"picture"];;
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString];
            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            [gVC setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
        }
}
```

Comment: What does your "`gVC`" "`setImage`" look like?  is it a "`@property`" or is it some method?

Comment: Also, since you go to the trouble of creating a "`tmpImage`" (which you don't use), did you check to make certain "`tmpImage`" is a valid object and not NULL?

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) UIImage *image;foodImageView.image=image;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your "`@property`" declaration to ***strong***.

I.E.

```
@property (strong) UIImage *image;
```

You need to have a retained image for it to be picked up in your new view controller.

Otherwise it will be disposed by the parent view controller when the "`prepareForSegue`" method finishes.

Comment: I have got it. Thanks a lot Michael. I will accept your answer untill stackoverflow allows me which left 8 min.